# java GUI how to save into text file

Tags: java, user-interface

i need to save texts from text boxes to text file but any code i found on or made it didn't work, any idea? like any at all? which code would work. i had to use java gui where my teacher teach us about java, but nothing about GUI so ii cant even make save to text file.

```
public class FlightsPanel extends JPanel {
private Flight flightSelected = null;
private JTextField textFieldDepartureAirport;
private JTextField textFieldArrivalAirport;
private JTextField textFieldDepartureDate;
private JTextField textFieldArrivalDate;
private JRadioButton rdbtnBoarding;
private JRadioButton rdbtnChecking;
private JRadioButton rdbtnAvailable;
private JRadioButton rdbtnClosed;
private JTextField textFieldCost;

private DefaultListModel<String> populateFlights() {
    DefaultListModel<String> list = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    ArrayList<Flight> FlightList = MainMenu.getAirlineMgr().getFlightList();

    for (int i = 0; i < FlightList.size(); i++) {
        list.addElement(FlightList.get(i).getFlightNumber());
    }

    return list;
}

private void displayFlight(String number) {
    flightSelected = MainMenu.getAirlineMgr().getFlightByNumber(number);
    textFieldDepartureAirport.setText(flightSelected.getDepartureAirport());
    textFieldArrivalAirport.setText(flightSelected.getArrivalAirport());
    textFieldDepartureDate.setText(flightSelected.getDepartureDate().toString());
    textFieldArrivalDate.setText(flightSelected.getArrivalDate().toString());
    textFieldCost.setText(Double.toString(flightSelected.getCost()));

    if (flightSelected.getFlightStatus() == Flight.Status.AVAILABLE) {
        rdbtnAvailable.setSelected(true);
    } else {
        if (flightSelected.getFlightStatus() == Flight.Status.BOARDING) {
            rdbtnBoarding.setSelected(true);
        } else {
            if (flightSelected.getFlightStatus() == Flight.Status.CHECKING) {
                rdbtnChecking.setSelected(true);
            } else {
                if (flightSelected.getFlightStatus() == Flight.Status.CLOSED) {
                    rdbtnClosed.setSelected(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void saveFlight() {
    flightSelected.setDepartureAirport(textFieldDepartureAirport.getText());
    flightSelected.setArrivalAirport(textFieldArrivalAirport.getText());
    flightSelected.setCost(Double.parseDouble(textFieldCost.getText()));

    // flightSelected.setDepartureDate(textFieldDepartureDate.getText());
    // flightSelected.setArrivalDate(textFieldArrivalDate.getText());

    if (rdbtnAvailable.isSelected()) {
        flightSelected.setFlightStatus(Flight.Status.AVAILABLE);
    } else {
        if (rdbtnBoarding.isSelected()) {
            flightSelected.setFlightStatus(Flight.Status.BOARDING);
        } else {
            if (rdbtnChecking.isSelected()) {
                flightSelected.setFlightStatus(Flight.Status.CHECKING);
            } else {
                if (rdbtnClosed.isSelected()) {
                    flightSelected.setFlightStatus(Flight.Status.CLOSED);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public FlightsPanel() {
    setBackground(new Color(175, 238, 238));
    setLayout(null);

    JList list = new JList(populateFlights());
    list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            displayFlight(list.getSelectedValue().toString());
        }
    });
    list.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true));
    list.setBounds(141, 161, 89, 81);
    add(list);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Available flights:");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(141, 136, 121, 14);
    add(lblNewLabel);

    textFieldDepartureAirport = new JTextField();
    textFieldDepartureAirport.setBounds(206, 36, 112, 20);
    add(textFieldDepartureAirport);
    textFieldDepartureAirport.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Departure Airport:");
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(206, 11, 112, 14);
    add(lblNewLabel_1);

    textFieldArrivalAirport = new JTextField();
    textFieldArrivalAirport.setColumns(10);
    textFieldArrivalAirport.setBounds(10, 36, 112, 20);
    add(textFieldArrivalAirport);

    JLabel lblArrivalAirport = new JLabel("Arrival Airport:");
    lblArrivalAirport.setBounds(10, 11, 112, 14);
    add(lblArrivalAirport);

    textFieldDepartureDate = new JTextField();
    textFieldDepartureDate.setColumns(10);
    textFieldDepartureDate.setBounds(206, 91, 192, 20);
    add(textFieldDepartureDate);

    JLabel lblDepartureDate = new JLabel("Departure Date:");
    lblDepartureDate.setBounds(206, 67, 112, 14);
    add(lblDepartureDate);

    textFieldArrivalDate = new JTextField();
    textFieldArrivalDate.setColumns(10);
    textFieldArrivalDate.setBounds(10, 91, 192, 20);
    add(textFieldArrivalDate);

    JLabel lblArrivalDate = new JLabel("Arrival Date:");
    lblArrivalDate.setBounds(10, 66, 112, 14);
    add(lblArrivalDate);

    rdbtnBoarding = new JRadioButton("BOARDING");
    rdbtnBoarding.setBounds(10, 211, 112, 23);
    add(rdbtnBoarding);

    rdbtnChecking = new JRadioButton("CHECKING");
    rdbtnChecking.setBounds(10, 237, 112, 23);
    add(rdbtnChecking);

    rdbtnAvailable = new JRadioButton("AVAILABLE");
    rdbtnAvailable.setBounds(10, 159, 112, 23);
    add(rdbtnAvailable);

    JLabel lblStatus = new JLabel("Status:");
    lblStatus.setBounds(20, 138, 220, 14);
    add(lblStatus);

    rdbtnClosed = new JRadioButton("CLOSED");
    rdbtnClosed.setBounds(10, 185, 112, 23);
    add(rdbtnClosed);

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(rdbtnBoarding);
    group.add(rdbtnChecking);
    group.add(rdbtnAvailable);
    group.add(rdbtnClosed);

    JButton button = new JButton("Cancel");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            MainMenu.hideFlights();
        }
    });
    button.setBounds(10, 269, 89, 23);
    add(button);

    JButton btnConfirm = new JButton("Confirm");
    btnConfirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            saveFlight();
            MainMenu.hideFlights();

        }
    });
    btnConfirm.setBounds(351, 269, 89, 23);
    add(btnConfirm);

    JLabel lblCost = new JLabel("Cost:");
    lblCost.setBounds(341, 11, 112, 14);
    add(lblCost);

    textFieldCost = new JTextField();
    textFieldCost.setColumns(10);
    textFieldCost.setBounds(328, 36, 112, 20);
    add(textFieldCost);
}
```

}[pic of design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ0g8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic file writing from Java.  The only difference here from basic file writing is that you need to get the Strings to write from the text attributes of your objects.  Here is one example from your code:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;

try{
    PrintWriter fileWriter = new PrintWriter("myFile.txt", "UTF-8");
    fileWriter.println(textFieldDepartureAirport.selectAll());
    fileWriter.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Since your teacher did not include much about the UI items, you are able to look up the JavaDoc info about the object type that is holding the data.  For example, your text boxes are declared as JTextField, so you can find more info about this class here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html